# mysql select records with sum of two column less than a column

Tags: mysql, sql

i am trying to write query which can select all records with below conditions
**sum of column a and b to be less than c**
i wrote below code but it does not works :

```
SELECT *,(`a` +`b`) as newfinal,c FROM mytable WHERE newfinal<c

SELECT *  FROM mytable WHERE (`a` +`b`) < c
```

i am stuck with it can u please help me with my query

Comment: The second query should work, though you can try removing the backticks to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: no does not worked

Comment: are you getting error message

Comment: some some typo issue was there

Comment: some some typo issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tried this on my stats database - works for me

```
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE (athomegoalswon +athomegoalslost) < yellowcards
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This one it will work for me

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE (a+b) < c
```

Answer (score 0):

Try HAVING instead of WHERE in your query

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).